# Django ChoiceField. How to pass initial value to the form

Tags: django, django-forms

Sorry, I am a beginner. How to pass the variable / value x = "ABCDE" to the form?

```
#views.py
     ...
     x = "ABCDE"
     form1 = KSS_Form1(initial={'x':x})
     context = {'form':form1, **context}
     return render(request, 'af/size/01_kss_size2.html', context)
```

```
#forms.py
class KSS_Form1(forms.Form):
    mat_geh_innen = forms.ChoiceField(choices=[], widget=forms.Select())
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
         super(KSS_Form1, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
         self.initial['mat_geh_innen'] = x
         self.fields['mat_geh_innen'].choices = \
            [(i.id, "Housing: " + i.mat_housing.descr) \
            for i in afc_select_housing_innenteile.objects.filter(Q(series__valuefg__exact=x) & Q(anw_01=True))]
```

as for now I get an error message
`Exception Value:   name 'x' is not defined`

How shall I pass 2, 3, or more values if I have a number of different ChoiceFields in the Form?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You can obtain this from the `self.initial` dictionary:

#forms.py

```
class KSS_Form1(forms.Form):
    mat_geh_innen = forms.ChoiceField(choices=[], widget=forms.Select())
    
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
         super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
         self.fields['mat_geh_innen'].initial = self.initial['x']
         self.fields['mat_geh_innen'].choices = [
             (i.id, 'Housing: ' + i.mat_housing.descr)
             for i in 
             afc_select_housing_innenteile.objects.filter(series__valuefg=x, anw_01=True)
         ]
```

You however might want to look to a [**`ModelChoiceField`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/forms/fields/#django.forms.ModelChoiceField) that makes it more convenient to select model objects.

Comment: Sorry, the same errror message.
```
 /home/oleg/Desktop/element/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py in _get_response

                    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

▶ Local vars
/home/oleg/Desktop/final_ael_rsf/ako/af/views.py in n01_size_kss

                    form1 = KSS_Form1(initial={'x':x})

▶ Local vars
/home/oleg/Desktop/final_ael_rsf/ako/af/forms.py in __init__

                 afc_select_housing_innenteile.objects.filter(series__valuefg=x, anw_01=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

[Willem Van Onsem](https://stackoverflow.com/users/67579/willem-van-onsem), thank you for the hint.
For me this was the solution.

```
class KSS_Form1(forms.Form):
    mat_geh_innen = forms.ChoiceField(choices=[], widget=forms.Select())
    
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
         super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
         x = self.initial['x']
         self.fields['mat_geh_innen'].choices = [
             (i.id, 'Housing: ' + i.mat_housing.descr)
             for i in 
             afc_select_housing_innenteile.objects.filter(series__valuefg=x, anw_01=True)
         ]
```